# Export Parse Class to Excel using Excel PowerQuery?

Tags: excel, parse-platform, powerquery

i need to fetch a parse table of my parse app into Microsoft Excel 2013. I found a clean solution: use excel powerQuery. The problem is that parse.com reject autentication..
excel powerquery ask me an url and i put: https://api.parse.com/1/Classes/myClassName and key i use myRestKey but won't work. Excel says bad autentication.

how can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be great to have a PowerBI data source extension for parse.com, you can vote for that here: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi/suggestions/10340982-parse

---

You can access the raw REST endpoint manually, but it involves manually setting your rest key in the query text (not great for security, so don't share your workbook).

Add this code as a query in the Power Query advanced editor. (Go Power Query > Get External Data > From Other Sources > Blank Query > View > Advanced Editor > overwrite the existing code with this code)

You'll need to replace `MyAppID` and `MyAPIKey` with your personal values, which you can find at parse.com > YourApplication > Core > API Console > Endpoint "/user/" > Click [Export to cURL]

```
let
    Query1 = Web.Contents("https://api.parse.com/1/users/", [Headers = [#"X-Parse-Application-Id" = MyAppID, #"X-Parse-REST-API-Key" = MyAPIKey]]),
    #"Imported JSON" = Json.Document(Query1),
    results = #"Imported JSON"[results],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(results, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"createdAt", "objectId", "updatedAt", "username"}, {"createdAt", "objectId", "updatedAt", "username"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

Just choose anonymous credentials for https://api.parse.com/, since you're not storing any credentials outside the query.

Comment: Hi, I voted to develop PowerBI data source extension. I have a question.. where i can put your code in Excel to fetch data?

Comment: Works! I found that the keys must be between "" but work!

Comment: I have another question.. how can edit Request to Include a pointer key?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... Can you start a new question?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to include key:

```
Query1 = Web.Contents("https://api.parse.com/1/classes/ClassName", [ Query=[ #"include"="keyName"], Headers = [#"X-Parse-Application-Id" = "myAppKey", #"X-Parse-REST-API-Key" = "myRestKey"]])
```